# How to create a responsive website without using bootstrap, mediaquery, any other frameworks

Tags: html, css, responsive

how to create a responsive website **without using bootstrap, media query, any other frameworks**?

**only use html,css** how to creat responsive web site please help me?

we can create with `<div>` or any other ? but it should be **responsive in all device**.

```
<div class='headr'></div>
<div class='cont'></div>
<div class='art'></div>
<div class='img'></div>
<div class='footer'></div>
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Without media queries, you will have no chance to make it responsive

Comment: any old method for it ?

Comment: Sorry, if you don't use a pot to hold water, then how can you store the water in air??

You are excluding all possible ways to get some solutions, then actually you have no intention to get the solution.

Comment: Still you have some options, but they may not suite all devices always. It completely depends upon the design you are having, and how complex it is.

Comment: You can write an HTML page with no styling at all, just the meta viewport tag, and call it "responsive". The "old method" was that of having a mobile website on its own and keeping the frontend code for the desktop and mobile website separate. The new method is that of using media queries, relative units and so on.

Comment: `<div class='headr'></div>
<div class='cont'></div>
<div class='art'></div>
<div class='img'></div>
<div class='footer'></div>`

Comment: only need css for responvie

Comment: Then "only" write the according CSS. You will need media queries for that, and you will have much more work when you really want to avoid using a framework

Comment: You can use `flexbox` to make it flexible, but without media queries it will not be responsive.

Comment: Make a fluid design then

Comment: You can create your own framework using css flex and grid. If your project is a big size work, i don't recommend this way.

Comment: i got solution with javascript thanking you gusy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

     <link id='myAnchor' href="css/style2.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body onresize="myFunction()">
<div class='headr'>menu</div>

<div class='cont' ></div>
<div class='art'>art section</div>

<div class='img'>img section</div>
<div class='add'>add1 section</div>
<div class='footer'>add1 section</div>
```

> enter JavaScript responsive

```
function myFunction() {
    var w = window.outerWidth;
    if(w === 1024){
    document.getElementById("myAnchor").href = "css/style3.css";
    }else if(w < 960){
    document.getElementById("myAnchor").href = "css/style2.css";


    }else if(w < 700){
    document.getElementById("link").innerHTML = w +"css/style1";
    }
}
```

> you have to write **stylesheet** for every screen. if screen was
>   change the style sheet url will be change

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know for possible solutions you can use the percentage unit. But the use of media queries is recommended.
you can set CSS width to a certain percentage like:

```
.someClass {
      width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

media query is part of CSS it's not a framework but if you don't want to use it too you can use these Relative Lengths (%, VW) and min-width property